# Call Function via User Interaction with Office Scripts in Excel Online

Tags: excel-online, office-scripts

Is it possible to trigger an Office Scripts function within Excel Online as a result of a user action?  For example, can I run a specific Office Scripts function when the user clicks on a hyperlink within Excel Online?  If so, can you give an example of the syntax/setup of the hyperlink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to trigger based on user-action; we are investigating allowing trigger through a shape/image (button). Would that be something that'll meet your requirement?
(I work on the product team)

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Comment: That is something I have been wanting ever since Office Scripts was introduced! Thanks for the update Sudhi!

Comment: Happy to follow-up for more details. Please email at suramam (at) mirosoft . com for further questions.

Comment: Nope. C'mon guys, Office Scripts is Javascript. Javascript supports on-page events. I realize it might be *difficult* for you...

Answer (score 0):

You could try building a Flow (aka "a Power Automate") that is triggered on the "File Change event"(for the Excel file) in SharePoint. Instead of just having the Flow trigger on double-click you would need to enter data into the cell. Because the worksheet and, this, file changed the Flow would trigger. Good luck.